# pandas set index using split of column as new index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I get from a third party:

```
r = get_finance_rate([eq_opt_px.index[0],vol_opt_px.index[0]], expiry)
```

r:

```
    ticker                          field           value
0   SPX US 08/17/2018 C2830.0 Index OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.004648
1   VXX US 08/17/2018 C27.0 Index   OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.03248
```

Since the output is returned in a format that does not fits my needs I would like to reset the index. The obvious solution for what I'm trying to do is

```
r['aux id'] = [x.split()[0] for x in r['ticker']]
r = r.set_index('aux id')
```

Result:

```
    ticker                          field           value
SPX SPX US 08/17/2018 C2830.0 Index OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.004648
VXX VXX US 08/17/2018 C27.0 Index   OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.03248
```

However I would like to do something like

```
r = get_finance_rate([eq_opt_px.index[0],vol_opt_px.index[0]], expiry).set_index('ticker'.split(' ')[0])
```

The previous instruction does not perform the split

```
ticker                          field           value
SPX US 08/17/2018 C2830.0 Index OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.004648
VXX US 08/17/2018 C27.0 Index   OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.03248
```

Is there such a way to accomplish what I want without having to create the temporary column?

Comment: From doc of set_index - __Set the DataFrame index (row labels) using one or more *existing* columns.__ Looks like the index column has to be part of the dataframe.

Comment: The column exists, guess my question is to what extent you can apply functions during the assignation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for a one-liner:

```
r = get_finance_rate([eq_opt_px.index[0],vol_opt_px.index[0]], expiry)\
       .pipe(lambda x: x.set_index(x.ticker.str.split().str[0]).rename_axis('aux_id')
```

IIUC, you have to do this in two steps:

```
r = get_finance_rate([eq_opt_px.index[0],vol_opt_px.index[0]], expiry)
r = r.set_index(r.ticker.str.split().str[0]).rename_axis('aux_id')
```

Output:

```
                                 ticker           field     value
aux_id                                                           
SPX     SPX US 08/17/2018 C2830.0 Index  OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.004648
VXX       VXX US 08/17/2018 C27.0 Index  OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.032480
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. The thing is I would like to do everything in one line.   Otherwise, I like this approach :)

Comment: @Yuca if you want to go down this root, can you change the function `get_finance_rate` to incorporate the index changes you would like. Seems like the most logical solution.

Comment: @Yuca  Give that a try.

Comment: @WStokvis Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index=df.ticker.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
df.ticker=df.ticker.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r.assign(aux_id = lambda x: x['ticker'].str.split(expand = True)[0])
    .set_index('aux_id')
                                ticker           field     value
aux_id
SPX   SPX US 08/17/2018 C2830.0  Index  OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.004648
VXX   VXX US 08/17/2018 C27.0    Index  OPT_FINANCE_RT  2.032480
```